# How to copy qrc resource file into filesystem?

Tags: c++, qt

I wonder how to copy file that is embeded into app qrc into fs? Stuff like

```
QFile::copy("qrc:/assets/files/my.file" , "C:/my.file");
```

seems not to work. Why and how to make it to?

Comment: Is that the correct resource dir?  Normally they just begin with a `:`.

Comment: If you use the non-static version: QFile f("qrc:/..."); f.copy("C:/my.file"), f.errorString() might give a hint.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need the `qrc`, resources start with a `:`

eg `QFile myFile(":/data/data.xml");`

PS: I'm not sure how QFile treats case sensitiveness on resource filenames. For best portability you might want to make sure the case matches whatever is in your `qrc` file.