# How to use Qt resource for ttf font in libharu?

Tags: c++, qt, embedded-resource, libharu

I'm creating a Qt application that writes a pdf file using *libharu*. The true-type-font that is used in the pdf file shall be embedded into the binary file, so it is available on all platforms. For this, I want to use the Qt resource system.

The font file should be used as follows

```
const char* fontName = HPDF_LoadTTFontFromFile(doc,"path/to/myfont.ttf",HPDF_TRUE);
documentFont = HPDF_GetFont(doc,fontName,"ISO8859-2");
```

where I want the filename and path to be replaced by a resource name (e.g. `:/fonts/myfont.ttf`).
Is there a way to achieve this?

The options that I think of:

- Somehow pass the file content as a string or char array (as it is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33922284/read-an-image-from-a-qrc-using-imread-of-opencv)). This is not possible as the functions in *libharu* require a filename. There are no functions that require the actual file content.
- Save the resource content to a temporary file and use the temporary file name in the *libharu* function.

Are there any other more simple solutions for this? Thanks.

#### Solution:

Actually the second option was easier than expected. With the answer by [robin.thoni](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2626244/robin-thoni) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10724899/how-to-copy-qrc-resource-file-into-filesystem), I obtained this pretty simple solution:

```
std::string fontFile = std::tmpnam(nullptr);
QFile::copy(":/fonts/myfont.ttf",QString::fromStdString(fontFile));
const char* fontName = HPDF_LoadTTFontFromFile(doc,fontFile.c_str(),HPDF_TRUE);
```

Comment: What's wrong with the second option?

Comment: It should work but I don't like the idea to write a file from the code to the filesystem and read the same file again from the same code. I would think that there is a more simple way and I wonder if no one else ever needs to pass a file from a Qt resource to a non-Qt function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see here [How to access resource image with fopen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11154118/how-to-access-resource-image-with-fopen), there's no way to 'open' a Qt resource file using standard open/fopen, so you won't be able to craft a valid path to it. You will need to use your second option. You could use [std::tmpnam](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/tmpnam) to achieve it.